# .NET Core JWTBearerAuthentication Extension

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm currently working on integrating JWT Token Authentication in my .NET Core WebAPI and have successfully set up the authentication middleware as such in the Startup.CS

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
          ...
        }
```

I would like to insert my custom claims validation logic but have found no useful documentation that explains how and where to extend or inject my logic to.

A specific use case would be to check for the JTI claim within the incoming token against a list of blacklisted JTIs, and if found, rejects the token.

So far, I've tried writing up another middleware with the above logic and inserting it after the UseJwtBearerAuthentication, but I'm not sure whether it is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've previously written a middleware to be inserted in between the built in UseJwtBearerAuthentication middleware to validate the JTI claims against a blacklist but could not direct the response properly.

**I have since then moved the logic to a Custom Authorization Policy Handler. After that, I just tagged my controllers with the [Authorized(Policy = [PolicyName])] annotation.**

I am not sure that it is the best way to handle this so I'm still open to hear how you all would have done this, specifically an extension of the Authentication Middleware, overwriting it with custom validation or wiring up another custom validation middleware maybe?

---

Here's how to go about creating a Custom Authorization Policy Handler:

[Microsoft - Custom Policy-Based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies#security-authorization-policies-based)

---

I've explored the possibilities of a middleware to invalidate incoming JWT Tokens. However, I noticed that upon short-circuiting of the request, the status codes and response messages will be affected as the middleware will pass it back to the default JwtBearerAuthentication middleware which will effect its own status and response messages.